# Getting error while invoking API using AWS Lambda. (AWS Lambda + AWS API Gateway+ Postman)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I get an error while invoking the AWS SageMaker endpoint API from a Lambda function. When I call this using Postman, I am getting an error like:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "module initialization error"
}
```

Comment: this is what many of us have encountered and many questions are present on stackOverflow about it also - it would help if you share the URL of the exact API call with the data that you are sending to API gateway

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear, you can't call SageMaker endpoints directly using PostMan (even if it is, it would not be straightforward).
You may need to use AWS SDK (i.e. boto) for that.

Ref : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/call-an-amazon-sagemaker-model-endpoint-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/

What I would suggest is to create a small HTTP server with Flask and use the AWS SDK (Boto) to call the endpoint. Then you can call your Flask endpoint using PostMan.

Answer (score 0):

We recommend using AWS SDK to invoke your endpoint. AWS SDK clients handle the serialization for you as well as request signing, etc. It would be really hard to get it right manually with postman.

We have the SDK client available in many languages, including Java, Python, JS, etc.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_runtime_InvokeEndpoint.html#API_runtime_InvokeEndpoint_SeeAlso

Answer (score 0):

Next time please include more details in your question. eg. POST request data, Headers etc.

Anyways, to help you out in calling Sagemaker endpoint using Postman -

1. In 'Authorization' tab, select type as 'AWS Signature'.
2. Enter your Access and Secret key of the IAM user which has permission to Sagemaker resources.
3. Enter the AWS region. eg.us-east-1
4. Enter 'Service Name' as 'sagemaker'
5. Select the right content type. Some ML algorithms only accept 'text/csv'.
6. Select request type as 'POST'
7. Enter the Sagemaker Invocation url. eg:'https://runtime.sagemaker.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/endpoints/xgboost-xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xxx/invocations'

Try it out and let me know if you have any issues.

Here is how your Postman should look -
[image: Sagemaker endpoint request - Postman Screenshot]

Comment: @praneeth-peiris Have a look. You can call Sagemaker endpoint using Postman.